# Using FFMPEG to Batch Convert a Series of Separate Image Sequences

Tags: image, batch-file, ffmpeg, sequences

I am trying to convert a large set of image sequences (each contained within its own subfolder) to video files.  I can currently convert one sequence at a time by using ffmpeg and this code:

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -i "Image%%05d.jpg" -vf scale=1376:768 -qscale:v 2 "Display 1.m2v"
```

I also occasionally batch convert avi files which are contained within a single folder using:

```
for %%a in ("*.avi") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -qscale:v 2 "%%~na.m2v"
```

I assumed I'd be able to use this batch approach with separate image sequences.
What I’m having trouble with is figuring out the syntax for a similar batch code that will convert whatever image sequence is present in a folder (or subfolder) using the `anyfile%%05d` naming convention.  The `%%a` syntax in the second line of code doesn’t seem to be compatible with the way ffmpeg recognizes image sequences `anyfile%%05d` in the first.  Any thoughts?

Comment: already been asked. u could check ans here : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114908/bash-script-to-convert-all-flac-to-mp3-with-ffmpeg

Comment: Are you looking for a way to automate the generation of the single sequences or to combine these sequences into one file or both? Details on the folder structure may help then.

Comment: @RobertRowntree And a shell script would help a windows batch-file user how?

Comment: Just looking to generate separate video files, not stitch them together.  One video for each sequence, each sequence contained within a subfolder in one main folder.

Answer (score 0):

According to your last comment all you need is then to:

- iterate the subfolders of a base dir and evtl.
- cd/pushd in there run your one working line and
- step out and repeat until all subfolders are processd.

This is quite basic batch stuff.

```
@echo off

Pushd "X:\folder\to\start"
For /D %%A in (*) do (
    Pushd "%%~fA"
    ffmpeg -r 30 -i "Image%%05d.jpg" -vf scale=1376:768 -qscale:v 2 "Display 1.m2v"
    PopD
)
PopD
```